# How to save image in mongo data using node and angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, mean

I want to save image into database one of my web application. I am using MEAN architecture for this. What is the best way to do this? Please help me out with some proper example, tutorial or guidance.

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB we cannot store data whose size is more than 16MB, whereas images can easily exceed the size based on the resolution of the image.

Use [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) to store images - GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed the BSON-document size limit of 16 MB.

Instead of storing a file in a single document, GridFS divides the file into parts, or chunks [1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/), and stores each chunk as a separate document. By default, GridFS uses a chunk size of 255 kB; that is, GridFS divides a file into chunks of 255 kB with the exception of the last chunk. The last chunk is only as large as necessary.

Sample Implementations for storing and retrieving images using GridFS

NodeJS and GridFS

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle2.html

https://medium.com/@alvenw/how-to-store-images-to-mongodb-with-node-js-fb3905c37e6d#.268827v7s